# how do you make an actual *song* in Figure?

Tags: software

I've started playing around with Figure and I'm really enjoying it, but I'm a little lost. I've gone through the entire tutorial but it only teaches me how to make loops. it's great that a loop can be 1, 2, 4 or 8 bars, but that's still a loop, not a song. then I go to the archive of Figure songs that people have shared, and they're full-length songs, multiple loops sequenced together. is there a way to do this in Figure that I'm not getting, or do I have to export each loop individually and then use a different program to put them together?

Answer (score 1):

It's live loop-based software; It's a case of creating, adding and taking away loops on-the-fly while recording. There's no arranger.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this query was posted 5 months ago but thought I could help others seeking similar answers.

If you have a fairly recent device, using interapp audio to place your loops in something like GarageBand would be the way to build songs out of loops.  It works quite well on my 5th gen touch, rather seamless actually.  Gives me all the fun and simplicity of Figure coupled with the ability to get as creative and long winded as I may wish.  Adding vocals, other instruments is right there as well, pretty decent combination overall.